# Is the destructor of Arc guaranteed to be called before upgrading a Weak reference will return None?

Tags: rust, thread-synchronization

Is the destructor (`Drop`) of the wrapped value of `std::sync::Arc` guaranteed to be called / finished before the call of `upgrade` of a `std::sync::Weak` reference to the same object of any other thread may result in `None`?

I do need this in order to ensure that a reference counted value is a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

No.  What you're asking for would require `upgrade` to block while the the value is being dropped.  This is a bad idea in general because it could cause a deadlock in unexpected places.

It's hard to suggest a better solution without knowing what you're doing; what is the shared resource in question?